# Archivo application.properties en Spring Boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

me pregunto si existe una manera de modificar el archivo application.properties?

```
spring.profiles.active=server
```

necesito cambiar el valor de "server", pero lo necesito cambiar desde el front end. Ya sea por un select, que me permita seleccionar oracle o server. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Los perfiles (profiles) de Spring se usan para inicializar el contexto de la aplicación con una configuración u otra. Pero estando la aplicación en ejecución no tendrá efecto modificar el valor de la clave de configuración que indicas. No se que es lo que quieres lograr realmente pero este no es el camino correcto.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es mandar sobrescribir el archivo con un socket o bien utilizar una conexión ssh, telnet o ftp para modificar el archivo vía remota.

Comment: @AlanRodríguez, modificar el archivo no es un problema, el problema es que para que el cambio de perfil tenga efecto será necesario reiniciar la aplicación y ya si la reinicias no necesitas modificar el archivo, solo agregar un parámetro para indicar el perfil deseado.

Comment: Gracias a todos, es lo que me temia, el reinicio de la aplicacion, de hecho asi lo he hecho

Comment: el spring profile es para definir los parámetros de inicio de la aplicación en diferentes perfiles, si puedes dar mas detalles de porque necesitas cambiar el perfil desde un aplicación front-end te podríamos ayudar a buscar una solución optima. por ejemplo si fuese el caso que necesitas conectar 2 bases de datos diferentes puedes definir 2 DataSource independientes y así realizar las consultas por un único servicio o servicios individuales.

Comment: De hecho ese era el porque de mi duda, tengo conectar la misma aplicacion a dos base de datos, por eso tengo dos perfiles diferentes, una para cada bd.